# How is the plot/storyline of the movie "Twister" (1996) predictable?

Tags: analysis, twister

I don't understand how the plot/storyline of the movie [*Twister* (1996)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0117998/) is predictable.

Comment: Who says that it *is* predictable? We're missing some context here.

Answer (score 2):

[Foreshadowing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreshadowing) is a device used within a movie, play or other literary work whereby certain events or topics happen that later become the center of the story.  For instance, when the crew discuss the categories of tornados, and talk about the "Finger of God", and then later a tornado of that magnitude becomes the center of the movie, that's "foreshadowing".

Twister was rife with foreshadowing.  So much so that certain events were easily predictable.  Bill and Jo getting back together in a time of crisis; easily predictable.  Jo hunting tornados to the point of almost getting killed by one; easily predictable.  Many other events as well.